# Nesting ${name:offset:length} and $() in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh

In zsh, `$()` lets me run the command inside the parenthesis and get the stdout, and `${name:offset:length}` lets me get a substring of the variable name. How can I nest the former inside the latter? As a concrete example, the following is valid.

```
base=$(basename $HOME)              # basename of user home directory -- temporary
user3=${base:0:3}                   # first three letters of $base
```

But can the same thing be achieved without defining the temporary?

I know that `user3=$(basename $HOME | cut -c 1-3)` will do the trick, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use cut.

Comment: perhaps `${USER:0:3}`

Comment: @P.... : Not a good idea as a general solution, though it might work in many installations. While the basename of a user's home directory is very often $USER, this is not necessarily the case.

Comment: @user1934428 agreed. this is only valid if OP's disro support this mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quotes around the command substitution should work:

```
user3=${"$(basename $HOME)":0:3}
```

Though, I'd be inclined to use zsh's `:t` modifier instead of basename:

```
${${HOME:t}:0:3}
```

The `:offset:length` form is only really there for bash compatibility. If you might have an old version of zsh you can also use the subscript form:

```
${${HOME:t}[0,3]}
```